# Writer vs WriterT in Haskell

Tags: haskell, monads

What is the difference between `Writer` and `WriterT` in Haskell? Is one preferred over the other?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The difference is that `Writer` is a monad, whereas `WriterT` is a [monad transformer](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Monad_transformers), i.e. you give it some underlying monad, and it gives you back a new monad with "writer" features on top. If you only need the writer-specific features, use `Writer`. If you need to combine its effects with some other monad, such as `IO`, use `WriterT`.

Comment: Also note that `Writer` is defined by means of `WriterT`. More precisely, we have `type Writer w = WriterT w Identity`. Here `Identity` is a monad that has no effect. That is, we give `WriterT` a monad without effect and get the `Writer` monad.

Comment: I've never been able to figure out which way up to visualize a `Monad` stack.  Here, you say that the writer features are on top, but to access the `Monad` below, you use `lift`, which makes me visualize the writer as being on the bottom.

Comment: @pat: Well, the way I think of it, you're lifting the lower monad up to the same level as the writer.

Answer (score 4):

To add to the excellent explanations above, I'd like to also point to this paper. Has helped me quite a bit:

[Monad Transformers Step By Step](https://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/scravy/realworldhaskell/materialien/monad-transformers-step-by-step.pdf)

Comment: This link happens to 404, here is a new link for those who stumble upon this as I have: https://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/scravy/realworldhaskell/materialien/monad-transformers-step-by-step.pdf

Comment: This is 404ing again.